# let a and b be constants and let yj=axj+b for j=1,2....n. What are the relationships betwee...

Tags: statistics

let $a$ and $b$ be constants and let $yj=ax_j+b$ for $j=1,2....n.$ What are the relationships between the means of $y$ and $x$, and the standard deviations of $y$ and $x$?

I'm not sure what they are wanting here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess they just want you to relate expectations and variances of $y_j$ wWith $x_j$ by just applying $E$ and $Var$ on both sides. That is

$$E[y_j] = E[a x_j + b] = aE[x_j] + b$$
where we just used the linearity of the expectation.

For the variance you have
$$Var[y_j] = Var[a x_j + b] = Var[a x_j] + Var[b]  = Var[ax_j] = a^2 Var[x_j]$$
where we just used that the variance of a random variable plus a constant is the sum of the variances (this is not true if you have the sum of two dependent random variables) and we also used that the variance of a constant is indeed 0. Finally, we used that the constants multiplying can be pulled out to the square.

To get the standard deviation just take square root. So
$$\sigma_{y_j}  = a \sigma_{x_j} \mbox{  for all  } j=1,\dots,n$$
where $\sigma$ denotes the standard deviation.

The conclusion is that the standard deviation of the $y_j$'s are proportional to the standard deviations of the $x_j$'s by $a$ units.